# CSS Media Queries & Selectors

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, media-queries

If I understand Media Queries correctly, code like this:

```
@media (max-width:900px){...}
```

runs based off of the the html tag + the vertical scrollbar if it is visible.
I was wondering if it was possible to have it read a different selector, somehow.

Perhaps, something along these lines:

```
@media (#selector{max-width:900px}){...}
```

EDIT: I know anything is possible with jQuery, I am not looking for a jQuery solution.

Warmth.

Comment: Nope, not possible. You should use JS. Or provide some more code of your HTML content so we could try making a workaround for your case

Comment: You may also be interested to read [this](http://www.backalleycoder.com/2014/04/18/element-queries-from-the-feet-up/)

Comment: _“runs based off of the the html tag + the vertical scrollbar if it is visible”_ – nope. The basis for width-based media queries is the _viewport_.

Comment: but you can have #selector { @media (max-width:900px){...} }

Comment: You are asking for something like this : http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/06/25/media-queries-are-not-the-answer-element-query-polyfill/ and http://ianstormtaylor.com/media-queries-are-a-hack/ two great source to make you aware of what it's coming ;)

Comment: @CBroe, Yes, this is true, but what constitutes as the viewport in a PC when you resize the browser? I looked into this & it looks as thought it is the html tag + the scrollbar.

Comment: Nope, the viewport is the area used to display the page in the browser. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#viewport (And the `html` element _can_ be wider than this.)

Answer (score 1):

@medi is for detecting view port size.. If you need to check if current selector is less then 900px, so you need to do it with jQuery for example..

```
$(window).load(function(){

 var selectorWidth = $('#selector').width();

 if(selectorWidth <= 900) {

  /****do something here******/

}

})
```

or you can do the same in

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var selectorWidth = $('#selector').width();

 if(selectorWidth <= 900) {

  /****do something here******/

}

})
```

but better to do it after window load